# Sending Emails to Many Recipients in The 1000's Using Laravel and Mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I am using Laravel 5.5 and Mailgun. I want to send email campaigns to over 700 recipients and likely this list will grow into the thousands.  Currently I am looping through each email address and sending the emails one at a time. As a result usually only about 530 emails go out. I have searched the net and cannot seem to find a good explanation on how to approach this in a more efficient way so that all the emails are sent.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function mailCampaign()
{

    //Code to get all email data in JSON

    $emails= json_decode($data->getBody());
    $baseUrl = config('constants.base_url');

    foreach($emails as $key => $email){
        Mail::to($email)
            ->send(new EmailInstance($variable, $email, $baseUrl));
    }
    $data = ['message' => 'Success. Emails have been sent.'];
    return response()->view('emails.mail', $data, 200);
}
```

Comment: Put all mails / actions in a queue and process that queue regularly (every minute?) to process the oldest items.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't send emails one by one. Use Mailgun API instead. You can send thousands of emails using API with [Bogardo/Mailgun](https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun#batch-sending) package.

> Mailgun supports the ability send to a group of recipients through a single API call. This is achieved by specifying multiple recipient email addresses as to parameters and using Recipient Variables.

Comment: I found that. It says Note: Mailgun limits the number of recipients per message to 1000,  so I did not believe it would solve my issue.  I will try it, I may have interpreted this wrong.

Comment: @DukesNuz just use chunks. 1000 emails per chunk.

Comment: I was thinking in that direction, would you use Eloquent Chuncking?   Thanks all for all the input, I am new to Laravel and Mailgun.

Comment: Yes, I'd use Query Builder chunks. If you get the data from another source, Laravel has `chunk()` collection method.

Comment: Yeh, I am getting the data from another source. I am using Guzzle and the data is coming from a separate server. Data coming back in JSON format. Would chunk still work?

Comment: @DukesNuz in this case you can convert JSON to array with `json_decode($json, true)` and then use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). Or you can convert the array to collection and use `chunk()` collection method.

Comment: What I am confused about is when using Bogardo/Maigun Batch Sending, How does each email address get passed in tot he closure. Also what if there is more than one data set needed in the email blade? How would this get passed in? Thank you

Comment: Here is my code to send each email. I am missing something here and not sure what it is. I understand your post above regarding ```array_chunk()```  .
                                                                                                              
   ```foreach($emails as $key => $email){
         
            Mailgun::send('welcome', $data, function(Message $message){
                $message->to($email['email'], 'User One', [
                    'age' => 37,
                    'city' => 'New York'
                ]);
            });
        } ```

Comment: ...continued. I have nit used ```array_chunk()``` wanted to get Mailgun working first.